# How to fill a lot of circles in a circle with a diameter of 60mm, and all the inner circles are tangent

Tags: filling, geometry

I want to fill two circles with different diameters in a circle with a diameter of 60mm, the diameters of the two circles are 11mm and 7mm respectively. The inner circles are tangent respectively. The specific situation is shown in the figure.[image]

Comment: You seems to have filled already, what is the question?

Comment: This picture is generated using other software. I want to use mathematica to implement it, but I tried many times without success.

Answer (score 1):

```
R = 80
r1 = 10
r2 = 7
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], LightPurple, Disk[{0, 0}, R],
  LightRed, 
  Table[Disk[{2 r1*i - 60, -2 r1*j + 60}, r1], {i, 5}, {j, 5}],
  LightBlue, Opacity[0.3], 
  Table[Disk[{2 r2*i - 85, -2 r2*j + 70}, r2], {i, 2}, {j, 9}],
  Table[Disk[{2 r2*i + 43, -2 r2*j + 70}, r2], {i, 2}, {j, 9}],
  Table[Disk[{2 r2*i - 56, -2 r2*j + 85}, r2], {i, 7}, {j, 2}],
  Table[Disk[{2 r2*i - 56, -2 r2*j - 43}, r2], {i, 7}, {j, 2}]},
 Frame -> True]
```